# ¿Como mostrar un formulario al seleccionar una opción de mi select en Ionic?

Tags: angular, formularios, ionic, select, options

Soy estudiante y estoy aprendiendo en Ionic con Angular y tengo el siguiente select mi objetivo es mostrar distintos formularios de acuerdo a la opcion del select he investigado un poco y lo intente con js pero no lo logro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes colocar los formularios dentro un div, y ese div hacerlo visible de acuerdo al número del formulario seleccionado:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    
    @Component({
      template: `
      
      <select [(ngModel)]="formulario">
          <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
          <option value="1">Formulario 1</option>
          <option value="2">Formulario 2</option>
     </select>
    
    <div *ngIf="formulario == 1">
        mostrar formulario 1
    </div>
    
    <div *ngIf="formulario == 2">
        mostrar formulario 2
    </div>
      
      `
    })
    export class Formulario {
      formulario: number = 0;
    }
```